Fill a matrix in parallel - how to convert `Vec<Arc<Mutex<Vec<_>>>>` to Vec<Vec<_>>`
I'm learning Rust and just finished the Fearless Concurrency chapter in the Rust book, so am trying to fill up the rows of a matrix in parallel.
My matrix is large, so I send a chunk of rows to each thread, then the thread will fill the columns for all the rows of the chunk it is passed.
Here's how the matrix is defined and initialized with zeros:
// `rows` will be a matrix nrows x ncols.
// It will be filled in parallel, each threadig working on a chunk of rows.
let mut rows = vec![];
for _ in 0..nrows {
    // each row must be an `Arc<Mutex<_>>` since they'll be filled in parallel
    let row = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![0; ncols]));
    rows.push(row);
}

Then I do the parallel processing using thread::spawn and all works fine.
But then I end up with rows being type Vec<Arc<Mutex<Vec<usize>>>>, but from now on I just need an owned Vec<Vec<usize>>, so I convert it like this:
// Here is my question
// Now `rows` type is `Vec<Arc<Mutex<Vec<usize>>>>`
// and we want `Vec<Vec<usize>>`
let mut ret_rows = vec![];
for row in rows {
    ret_rows.push(row.lock().unwrap().clone())
}
// and return an owned vector
Vec::from_iter(ret_rows)

My question is if this conversion is being done efficiently?
I suspect that .clone() (and maybe Vec::from_iter()?) is making a copy of all the contents, which is not what I want and not really needed.

Here a minimalistic code reproducing my question:
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

/// Dummy worker filling up one all columns of one row
fn worker_row(row: &mut Vec<usize>, f: usize) {
    for i in 0..row.len() {
        row[i] = 2 * i * f  // dumb fill row with something
    }
}

/// Create and return a matrix of size `nrows` x `ncols`
fn build_matrix(ncols: usize, nrows: usize) -> Vec<Vec<usize>> {

    // `rows` will be a matrix nrows x ncols.
    // It will be filled in parallel, each threadig working on
    // a chunk of rows.
    let mut rows = vec![];

    // Initialise matrix with zeros.
    for _ in 0..nrows {
        // each row must be an `Arc<Mutex<_>>` since they'll be filled in parallel
        let row = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![0; ncols]));
        rows.push(row);
    }

    // Each thread will process a chunk of rows
    let nthreads = 8;
    let chunk_size = rows.len() / nthreads; // miss some, doesn't matter
    let mut handles = vec![];

    // Spawn threads
    for i in 0..nthreads {
        let mut rows_i = vec![];
        // Clone rows to be processes by this thread
        for r in i*chunk_size..(i+1)*chunk_size {
            rows_i.push(Arc::clone(&rows[r]));
        }
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            for r in i*chunk_size..(i+1)*chunk_size {
                let j = r - i * chunk_size;
                // acquire a lock
                let mut row = rows_i[j].lock().unwrap();
                worker_row(&mut row, r);
            }
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }
    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    // Here is my question
    // Now `rows` type is `Vec<Arc<Mutex<Vec<usize>>>>`
    // and I want `Vec<Vec<usize>>`
    // ?? Is this conversion done efficiently ??
    let mut ret_rows = vec![];
    for row in rows {
        ret_rows.push(row.lock().unwrap().clone())
    }
    // and return an owned vector
    Vec::from_iter(ret_rows)
}


fn main() {

    let rows = build_matrix(10, 24);
    for row in rows {
    println!("{:?}", row);
    }

}


Look into Arc::into_inner and Mutex::into_inner.

ret_rows already is a Vec so Vec::from_iter(ret_rows) doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

You don't need Arc at all when you use scoped threads you can just use a shared reference instead.

In case it's not obvious how to avoid unnecessary data cloning with into_inner(), here is your code modified to use it: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ab1a09bbb3e81ef0bc0737fdba2e3df3

@cafce25 regarding Vec::from_iter(ret_rows) I'm confused about mutability. ret_rows is mutable, I wanted to return something immutable. Apart from that, same same.

@cafce25 thanks for the tip regarding into_inner ... it was indeed making copies. after fixing that conversion to use into_inner rather than clone, benchmarking is running 30x faster for that part.

@Raf, mutability is a property of the binding, not the value. Vec::from_iter(ret_rows) is the same value as ret_rows just the former needlessly iterates and reallocates (if the compiler can't optimize it). See this Playground for an example.

@cafce25 makes sense. thanks again. the overhead was almost nothing, but nedless nonetheless. if you'd like to post your suggestions in an answer I'll accept it.

It's not clear why you even need a mutex here if the threads are all filling different rows. You can use split_at_mut to split a mutable slice into two parts. This plus scoped threads would eliminate both the Arc and the Mutex layers completely.
